# Help with statistics. Find confidence interval but i have no sigma.

Tags: statistics

I have this exercise that asks me to find a confidence interval of 95%, but I do not get any sigma, I know I can do the t student test based on degrees on freedom if I do not have the population st.dev, but in my case I do not even have the sample st.dev, can it be solved or the teacher made a mistake in the text ?

"The maturation time of maize plants follows the normal distribution. We follow 30 plants and it is seen that they reach maturity in 4 months. Construct a 95% confidence interval for the maturation time of the maize plant population."

In  order to find the margin of error i still need $ S $ (the sample st.dev) no ?

Otherwise how can i proceed ? Chi squared ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without any information about either the assumed or observed variance in the maturation time, it is not possible to construct a confidence interval or any interval estimate of the mean.  You could leave it as an unknown quantity; e.g., if the sample variance is $s^2$, then a $95\%$ confidence interval can be constructed as $$4 \pm t_{29,0.025}^* \frac{s}{\sqrt{30}}$$ where $t_{\nu, \alpha/2}^*$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of a student $t$ distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom. In this case, $$t_{29, 0.025}^* \approx 2.04523,$$ thus the CI for the mean maturation time as measured in months, is $$4 \pm 0.373406s,$$ where $s$ is the sample standard deviation.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on this and I was so confused, thank you , this was in one of my past exams and I was trying to solve them and couldn't . So the teacher either forgot to give more information and gave it during the exam , or he just wanted the 'parametric' answer with unknown S. Thank you again